# OpenCV python3 cannot rotate image back correctly

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-rotation

I want to use python3 with OpenCV packages to rotate an image in a degree 15 and rotate it back. However, the code below seem does not work but I think there no logic error in the codes. In the "NEAREST" window, the image is rotated correctly but in the "NEAREST-OK-RESTORE" window the image is not rotate back to its original position ( showed in "original" window ).

[image]

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#! -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import numpy as np

imgmat = cv2.imread('./lena.jpg',255)
print(hex(id(imgmat)))

cv2.imshow('original',imgmat)

rows,cols = imgmat.shape

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-15,1)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(src=imgmat,M=M,dsize=(cols,rows),flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
print(hex(id(dst)))
cv2.imshow('NEAREST',dst)


OKMM = cv2.invertAffineTransform(M)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(dst,OKMM,(cols,rows),flags = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
print(hex(id(dst)))
cv2.imshow('NEAREST-OK-RESTORE',dst)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The test image is here:
[image]

Comment: "seem does not work" -- in what sense? What are you expecting to get, and how does the result differ from that expectation? To me the result looks as expected -- the orientation of Lena is the same as in original, and the corners that fell outside the image area in the intermediate image are black, since that information was lost.

Comment: This is not similar to an undo operation. Pixels rotated out are forgotten, black pixels coming in become part of the picture. If you rotate backward, they will stay and additional new black pixels are rotated in.

Comment: @DanMašek OK thank you. The cropped images blind my eyes!

Comment: @guidot Thank you. I know what is the problem.

Comment: @Angusme I wrote an answer that solves your problem.  It uses the above concept to help you reconstruct the original image. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you for your kind help and the answer is accepted.

Comment: @Angusme You're welcome!  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because when you are performing the rotation, this is doing it within the span of the original image dimensions, so this results in image clipping if you are rotating the image and the resulting corner points extend beyond the original image dimensions.

What you have to do is zero pad the image so that the rotated image is fully contained within it, rotate this image then when you rotate back, you will have to crop the result.

To figure out how much to zero pad your image by, note that the largest possible dimensions of your image will be when the image is at a 45 degree rotation.  This means that the diagonal of the image would now be the number of rows in the image.  Therefore, zero pad your image so that we can at least store the image when subject to a 45 degree rotation, rotate this image and when you rotate back you'll have to crop the result.

You can use [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to do this for you and when you're done you can simply crop the result:

I've made the following changes to your code to do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

imgmat = cv2.imread('./lena.jpg',255)
print(hex(id(imgmat)))

cv2.imshow('original',imgmat)

rows,cols = imgmat.shape

# NEW - Determine the diagonal length of the image
diagonal = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(rows**2.0 + cols**2.0)))

# NEW - Determine how many pixels we need to pad to the top/bottom and left/right
pp_r, pp_c = (diagonal - rows) // 2, (diagonal - cols) // 2

# NEW - Pad the image
imgmat_copy = np.pad(imgmat, ((pp_r, pp_r), (pp_c, pp_c)), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0))

### Your code as before - note we are rotating the zero padded image
rows,cols = imgmat_copy.shape
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-15,1)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(src=imgmat_copy,M=M,dsize=imgmat_copy.shape,flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
print(hex(id(dst)))
cv2.imshow('NEAREST',dst)


OKMM = cv2.invertAffineTransform(M)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(dst,OKMM,(cols,rows),flags = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
print(hex(id(dst)))

# NEW - Crop the image
dst = dst[pp_r:-pp_r+1,pp_c:-pp_c+1]
cv2.imshow('NEAREST-OK-RESTORE',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I now get:

[image]